# htaccess how to correct mistake in file extension

Tags: .htaccess

in a bit of a panic, a newsletter has just gone out with an incorrect link, I'm assuming I can use the .htaccess file to redirect to the correct link, but I'm not having much luck
/walks-events/huguenot-footsteps/french-protestant-church-library.html.?acm=3466_63

the correct link is
/walks-events/huguenot-footsteps/french-protestant-church-library.html

basically I need to remove .?acm=3466_63 from the end of the url
I've tried a Redirect

```
Redirect /walks-events/huguenot-footsteps/french-protestant-church- 
library.html.?acm=3466_63 http://www.huguenotsofspitalfields.org/walks- 
events/huguenot-footsteps/french-protestant-church-library.html
```

but it does not appear to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your **top rule**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/walks-events/huguenot-footsteps/french-protestant-church-library\.html)\.\?acm=3466_63 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the uber quick reply. works perfectly!